# Is there any advantage to use newer "hid-compliant mouse" drivers?

Tags: drivers

I use razer death adder elite and i never used razer drivers, because they cause a lot of input lag... 
 And i have much better experience with generic "hid-compliant mouse" driver. But i wonder since they are from 2006, if there is any update.
 Generally is bad idea to download drivers from anywhere than manufacturer website, but i think one of website: driverscape.com is legit. 
  There are drivers even from 2014-03-18, v 5.80.3, i google version number and it showed some thread realting to logitech mouse. 
  They are amde for some specific mouse. Wondered if there could be some advantage getting newer drivers, since these are old as hell. 
  I also use windows sensitivity instead in game sensitivity, not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Windows drivers only *report* their build date as 2006, this is done so that if an driver is supplied by a manufacturer and listed to support the device you have then it will be preferred over the built-in driver supplied with Windows.

It works this way under the assumption that if you install a specific device driver then you will always use that driver instead under the assumption that you knew what you were doing.

That doesn't necessarily mean that the driver you install is "better".  The ones supplied with Windows may actually be newer or more complete.

Just because they are dated 2006 doesn't mean that that was when they were designed or built. They *could* have had an update last week, but been given a date of 2006.

You should use the driver that is provided by your manufacturer out of preference. If they don't supply a driver then you can assume the Windows built-in driver is "safe".

For more read the Microsoft Engineer blog [Why are all Windows drivers dated June 21, 2006? Don’t you ever update drivers?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170208-00/?p=95395) by Raymond Chen.

> My colleague Zac explains: When the system looks for a driver to use for a particular piece of hardware, it ranks them according to various criteria. If a driver provides a perfect match to the hardware ID, then it becomes a top candidate. And if more than one driver provides a perfect match, then the one with the most recent timestamp is chosen. If there is still a tie, then the one with the highest file version number is chosen.
>
> Suppose that the timestamp on the driver matched the build release date. And suppose you had a custom driver provided by the manufacturer. When you installed a new build, the driver provided by Windows will have a newer timestamp than the one provided by the manufacturer. Result: When you install a new build, all your manufacturer-provided drivers get replaced by the Windows drivers. Oops.
>
> Intentionally backdating the drivers avoids this problem. It means that if you have a custom manufacturer-provided driver, it will retain priority over the Windows-provided driver. On the other hand, if your existing driver was the Windows-provided driver from an earlier build, then the third-level selection rule will choose the one with the higher version number, which is the one from the more recent build.
>
> It all works out in the end, but it does look a bit funny.